# Changing the definition of the paragraph

Tags: newlines

I would like to change the definition of the paragraph in such a way that every line to be considered as a paragraph. As I understand from the documentation, one should change the variables `paragraph-start` and `paragraph-separate` for this purpose. I tried the following, but it doesn't work. (I have evaluated the following in the scratch buffer, but when using `forward-paragraph`, the usual definition of the paragraph is used by `forward-paragraph`).

```
(setq paragraph-start "\n"
       paragraph-separate "\n")
```

Comment: You can achieve this with `(setq paragraph-start "" paragraph-separate "\n")`, but it looks almost identical to `next-line`. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: @wvxvw After your comment I tried `(setq paragraph-start ""
       paragraph-separate "")`, but it has no effect. The old definition of paragraph is still used.

Comment: @wvxvw My motivation was to change the direction of lines provided by Emacs bidirectional support.

Comment: @wvxvw Sorry I had not seen `"\n"` seems to work.

Comment: FWIW, for any question about bidirectional text I recommend using `help-gnu-emacs@gnu.org`. The implementor of bidi in Emacs, and an expert on this kind of thing, reads that mailing list and often answers questions. Of course, you might also get a good answer here.

Comment: @wvxvw or OP: If the comment suggestion for `"\n"` works then please, someone, post that as an answer. Comments can be deleted at any time. OP: You can accept your own answer.